# Is there a way to periodically generate pages/posts in wordpress backend using javascript ajax function?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

What i need to do:

- Loop trough an array
- for each value in the array do an ajax call
- create a page if there is a result OR delete a page if there is no result

Here is some JavaScript i managed to write as an reference what i need:

```
const cities = [berlin, barcelona, london, paris, monaco, rome]
cities.forEach(function(city) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "example.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { action: 'city_search_form', city: city },
        success: function(result) {
            if (!result.includes("Text placeholder")) {
                
            // create a page with the array value "city" as the title

            } 
        }
    });
});
```

I need this to be done once a day.

I can't seem to find an answer if this is even possible

Comment: You can Schedule posts by default, Instead of publishing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the WordPress API and a php cron job (running once a day) to do the job. There you can also find, in the documentation, available [Wordpress API - Create page](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#create-a-page)